# P2P programing in C - Trying to implement a Bittorent Client using C

Tags: c, p2p, bittorrent

Network Programming classes have begun for us in the college and I too have been giving it a lot of reading for the past one month.
Now, when I have understood the OSI and other reference models including how various protocols like FTTP, HTTP, POP3, P2P etc works; I would like to apply my theoretical knowledge into practise.

So to accomplish the above task, I have chosen P2P protocol and I want to implement a bittorent-client (dummy) like utorrent. By the way, I'm skilled in C/C++/Java/C#.

Could anyone please guide me how shall I begin on this project and preferably which language I should use?

You are welcome to add your views If I'm missing on something.

Thanks for viewing.

Comment: Outdated,but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients - choose the first opensource windows based and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say if you are planning on developing this on a *nix platform, go with [libtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/). It is well-documented, C++ library, and a lot of popular linux bittorrent clients use it (e.g. rtorrent).

Comment: I have been working only on windows platform for quite a long time. Now I'm kind of habituated to it. Can you please suggest me an alternative in windows ?